# pyTube downloaded music cannot be used in reaper

Tags: python, audio, corruption, pytube, reaper

I used pytube to donwload a playlist I created in YouTube. All files can be played by media players I tried (Classic Media Player, VLC Media Player, Windows Media Player), but for some reason reaper cannot import them. Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

***This was the code I used***

```py
from pytube import Playlist, YouTube
from pathlib import Path

actual = Path.cwd()
guerilla = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8ig_PduC0sKgSva6_tzdfZCkLp7jdAFF")
ext = "mp3"

def checkAuthor(yt):
    if "-" not in yt.title:
        try:
            return yt.author.split(sep=" - ")[1]
        except IndexError:
            return yt.author
    else: return ""

for index, music in enumerate(guerilla):

    curr = YouTube(
        music,
        use_oauth=True,
        allow_oauth_cache=True
        )

    id = curr.streams.get_audio_only()

    Path.mkdir(filePath, exist_ok=True)
    filePath = actual / "music"
    name = str(index+1) + " " + checkAuthor(curr) + " - " + curr.title + "." + ext
    completePath = filePath/name
    curr.streams.filter(file_extension=ext)

    toDown = curr.streams.get_by_itag(id.itag)
    toDown.download(filePath,name, skip_existing=True)
```

I tried installing LAME, ffmpeg and VLC but none helped. Also I realized that I can use any other audiofiles I downloaded from the internet.

Comment: `id = curr.streams.get_audio_only()` FYI you should not call something `id` or any other built-in name.

Comment: There's lots and lots of potential debug info you did not include. If you run `curr.streams.filter(only_audio=True)` what are the results? What is the actual streaming format of the audio available? When you filter down via `curr.streams.filter`, what streams remain in `curr`? Does it actually remove unwanted ones from `curr`, have you verified that? From the source code of that library, it looks like it just _returns_ the filtered results but I haven't fully checked.

Comment: ^, filter out the videos with unsupported reaper video filetypes, and try loading it in.